# Collision detection in C Learning project issue Separating axis theorem

Tags: c, collision-detection

I've recently learned C for fun and am in the process of learning C++. As A Learning project I'm making a game in C using ALLEGRO5 library for display. I've got movement of a player on the field 2d isometric. I've created 2 parallelograms and I've already done non rotating squares collision.  a simple illustration:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtNX8.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/t28VD.png
Naturally player moves and house does not. I am detecting collision using vertices and so I send some Vertices:
`fresh(house.vertices_x, house.vertices_y, player.vertices_x, player.vertices_y, 5);` The players vertices have the position added to them all so that the calculation can move.

```
struct flipped_y { double y; double yp; };
    struct flipped_y flip_y[10];
    struct vectors { double x; double y; double xp; double yp; };
    struct vectors vector[10];
    struct Normals { double x; double y; double xp; double yp; };
    struct Normals normvec[10];
    struct Normalized { double x; double y; double xp; double yp; };
    struct Normalized normalized[10];
    struct projectpts { double pts; double ptsp; double ptspoly2rhom; double ptspoly2player; };
    struct projectpts project[20];
    struct maxmin { double max; double min; double maxp; double minp; double maxon2; double minon2; double maxpon2; double minpon2; };
    struct maxmin mm[5];
    double flipp_y_func(double verts[], double vertsp[], int numvert);
    double createvector(double vert_x[], struct flipped_y flip_y[], double vert_xp[], int numvert);
    double Normals(struct vectors vector[], int numvecs);
    double Normalize(struct Normals normvec[], int numvec);
    double ProjectPoints(double verts_x[], double verts_xp[], struct flipped_y flip[], struct Normalized normalized[], int numpts);
    double Compareminandmax(double max[], double maxp[], double min[], double minp[], double maxon2[], double maxpon2[], double minon2[], double minpon2[], int nummaxmin);
    int fresh(double vertices_x[], double vertices_y[], double pvertices_x[], double pvertices_y[],int numverts) {
        int i = 0, i2 = 0, i3 = 0, i4 = 0, i5 = 0, i6 = 0, i7 = 0,i8=0; double max[5] = { -INFINITY,-INFINITY,-INFINITY,-INFINITY,-INFINITY }, min[5] = { INFINITY,INFINITY,INFINITY,INFINITY,INFINITY }, maxp[5] = { -INFINITY,-INFINITY,-INFINITY,-INFINITY,-INFINITY }, minp[5] = { INFINITY,INFINITY,INFINITY,INFINITY,INFINITY };
        double maxon2[5] = { -INFINITY,-INFINITY,-INFINITY,-INFINITY,-INFINITY }, minon2[5] = { INFINITY,INFINITY,INFINITY,INFINITY,INFINITY }, maxpon2[5] = { -INFINITY,-INFINITY,-INFINITY,-INFINITY,-INFINITY }, minpon2[5] = { INFINITY,INFINITY,INFINITY,INFINITY,INFINITY };
        double wishbone = 1;
```

this is allegro topleft coords so we flip Y to cartesian taking house(vertices_y and player pvertices_y)

```
flipp_y_func(vertices_y, pvertices_y, 5);
```

now we create a vector

```
createvector(vertices_x, flip_y, pvertices_x, 5);
```

then we get the normals of both

```
  Normals(vector, 4);
```

normalize both

```
Normalize(normvec, 4);
```

and now we project both  onto themselves and the other shape

```
ProjectPoints(vertices_x, pvertices_x, flip_y, normalized, 4);
```

this is getting the max and min values of both house on normalized vectors 1-4 and player on normalized vectors 1-4

```
for (i6; i6 < 4; i6++) {
            for (i7 = 0; i7 < 4; i7++) {

                // polygon1
                if (project[i6 * 4 + i7].pts > max[i6]) { max[i6] = project[i6 * 4 + i7].pts; }
                if (project[i6 * 4 + i7].pts < min[i6]) { min[i6] = project[i6 * 4 + i7].pts; }

                //player

                if (project[i6 * 4 + i7].ptsp > maxp[i6]) { maxp[i6] = project[i6 * 4 + i7].ptsp; }
                if (project[i6 * 4 + i7].ptsp < minp[i6]) { minp[i6] = project[i6 * 4 + i7].ptsp; }
                //polygon2
                if (project[i6 * 4 + i7].ptspoly2rhom > maxon2[i6]) { maxon2[i6] = project[i6 * 4 + i7].ptspoly2rhom; }
                if (project[i6 * 4 + i7].ptspoly2rhom < minon2[i6]) { minon2[i6] = project[i6 * 4 + i7].ptspoly2rhom; }
                //player
                if (project[i6 * 4 + i7].ptspoly2player > maxpon2[i6]) { maxpon2[i6] = project[i6 * 4 + i7].ptspoly2player; }
                if (project[i6 * 4 + i7].ptspoly2player < minpon2[i6]) { minpon2[i6] = project[i6 * 4 + i7].ptspoly2player; }

            }
```

Print Values

//on 1

```
    /* printf("\nmax %f normvec%d", max[i6], i6);
            printf("\nmin %f normvec%d\n", min[i6], i6);
            printf("\nmaxPLAYER %f normvecPLAYER%d", maxp[i6], i6);
            printf("\nminPLAYER %f normvecPLAYER%d\n", minp[i6], i6);
            //on2
            printf("\nmaxon2 %f normvecon2%d", maxon2[i6], i6);
            printf("\nminon2 %f normvecon2%d\n", minon2[i6], i6);
            printf("\nmaxPLAYERon2 %f normvecPLAYERon2%d", maxpon2[i6], i6);
            printf("\nminPLAYERon2 %f normvecPLAYERon2%d\n", minpon2[i6], i6);*/

        }
    
now we compare min and max of each shape on all the normalized vectors of both shaoes        
       

wishbone = Compareminandmax(max, maxp, min, minp, maxon2, maxpon2, minon2, minpon2, 4);
```

Me wishing it will work lol

```
printf("\nwishbone %f", wishbone);
```

reference

/*aminbmin
or
bmin amin*/
Printing values to see how they compare and they arent reporting collision when they are supposed to but usually only on 1 or two axis

```
/*while (i < 4) {
            printf("\nmin%f < maxp%f and min%f > minp%f\n \t\t\t or \nminp%f < max%f and minp%f> min%f\n\n", min[i], maxp[i], min[i], minp[i], minp[i], max[i], minp[i], min[i]); 
            printf("\nminon2%f < maxpon2%f and minon2%f > minpon2%f\n \t\t\t or \nminpon2%f < maxon2%f and minpon2%f> minon2%f\n\n", minon2[i], maxpon2[i], minon2[i], minpon2[i], minpon2[i], maxon2[i], minpon2[i], minon2[i]); i++;
        
        }*/

        return 0;
    }
    
   

 //player and house flipped
    double flipp_y_func(double verts[], double vertsp[], int numvert) {
        int i;  for (i = 0; i < numvert; i++) {
            flip_y[i].y = verts[i] * -1;
            flip_y[i].yp = vertsp[i] * -1;


        }
    
 

       return 0;
    }
```

// vector created

```
double createvector(double vert_x[], struct flipped_y flip_y[], double vert_xp[], int numvert) {
    int i = 0; double vector_x[10], vector_y[10], vector_xp[10], vector_yp[10];
    for (i = 0; i < numvert; i++) {
        vector_x[i] = vert_x[i + 1] - vert_x[i];
        vector_y[i] = flip_y[i + 1].y - flip_y[i].y;
        vector[i].x = vector_x[i];
        vector[i].y = vector_y[i];
        //player
        vector_xp[i] = vert_xp[i + 1] - vert_xp[i];
        vector_yp[i] = flip_y[i + 1].yp - flip_y[i].yp;
        vector[i].xp = vector_xp[i];
        vector[i].yp = vector_yp[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

//get normal

```
double Normals(struct vectors vector[], int numvecs) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numvecs; i++) {
        normvec[i].y = vector[i].x;
        normvec[i].x = vector[i].y * -1;
        //player

        normvec[i].yp = vector[i].xp;
        normvec[i].xp = vector[i].yp * -1;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

//normalize anything with a p added means player

```
double Normalize(struct Normals normvec[], int numvec) {
    int i; double Normalizedx[6], Normalizedy[6], Normalizedxp[6], Normalizedyp[6], lengthp[6], length[6];
    for (i = 0; i < numvec; i++) {
        length[i] = sqrt(pow(normvec[i].x, 2) + pow(normvec[i].y, 2));
        Normalizedx[i] = normvec[i].x / length[i];
        Normalizedy[i] = normvec[i].y / length[i];
        normalized[i].x = Normalizedx[i];
        normalized[i].y = Normalizedy[i];


        lengthp[i] = sqrt(pow(normvec[i].xp, 2) + pow(normvec[i].yp, 2));
        Normalizedxp[i] = normvec[i].xp / lengthp[i];
        Normalizedyp[i] = normvec[i].yp / lengthp[i];
        normalized[i].xp = Normalizedxp[i];
        normalized[i].yp = Normalizedyp[i];
        
    }

    return 0;
}







double ProjectPoints(double verts_x[], double verts_xp[], struct flipped_y flip_y[], struct Normalized normalized[], int numpts) {
        int i = 0, g = 0; double dot[20], dotp[20], dotrhomonpoly2norm[20], dotplayeronpoly2norm[20];
        for (i = 0; i < numpts; i++) {
            for (g = 0; g < numpts; g++) {
                //polygon one projection of both polys verts
                dot[i * numpts + g] = ((verts_x[g] * normalized[i].x) + (flip_y[g].y * normalized[i].y));
                project[i * numpts + g].pts = dot[i * numpts + g];

                //player

                dotp[i * numpts + g] = ((verts_xp[g] * normalized[i].x) + (flip_y[g].yp * normalized[i].y));
                project[i * numpts + g].ptsp = dotp[i * numpts + g];


                //polygon two projection of both polys verts double ptspoly2rhom;double ptspoly2player;

               
                
                dotrhomonpoly2norm[i * numpts + g] = ((verts_x[g] * normalized[i].xp) + (flip_y[g].y * normalized[i].yp));
                project[i * numpts + g].ptspoly2rhom = dotrhomonpoly2norm[i * numpts + g];

                //player

                dotplayeronpoly2norm[i * numpts + g] = ((verts_xp[g] * normalized[i].xp) + (flip_y[g].yp * normalized[i].yp));
                project[i * numpts + g].ptspoly2player = dotplayeronpoly2norm[i * numpts + g];
                
                //dotplayeronpoly2norm[i * numpts + g] = ((verts_xp[g] * normalized[i].xp) + (flip_y[g].yp * normalized[i].yp));
                //project[i * numpts + g].ptspoly2player = dotplayeronpoly2norm[i * numpts + g];
                dotplayeronpoly2norm[16] = ((verts_xp[3] * normalized[3].xp) + (flip_y[3].yp * normalized[3].yp));

             

            }
        }



        return 0;
    }


double Compareminandmax(double max[], double maxp[], double min[], double minp[], double maxon2[], double maxpon2[], double minon2[], double minpon2[], int nummaxmin) {
        int i=0;
        /*amin<bmax and amin>bmin
                                      or
                bmin<amax and bmin> amin*/
        for (i = 0; i < nummaxmin;i++) {
           /* if ((min[i] < maxp[i] && min[i] > minp[i] || minp[i] < max[i] && minp[i] > min[i]) ||
                (minon2[i] < maxpon2[i] && minon2[i] > minpon2[i] || minpon2[i] < maxon2[i] && minpon2[i] > minon2[i])) {
                return 2;
            }*/
            if (((min[i]<maxp[i] && min[i]>minp[i]) || (minp[i]<max[i] && minp[i]>min[i])) || 
                ((minon2[i]<maxpon2[i] && minon2[i]>minpon2[i]) || (minpon2[i]<maxon2[i] && minpon2[i]>minon2[i]))) { return 22; }
           
        }
        
        
       
    return 4;}
```

now I've tried using the inequality formula but something is wrong I've been checking through and fixing some things and with some inequalities in the if statement I can get somewhat close to proper collision. like so[Collision detection I've been able to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtNX8.png)

So far I've been unable to detect what I'm doing wrong and I've double checked up to my dot product normalization with a graphing calculator. If you have any tips or easier ways I can do things let me know. But once I get it right I will simplify and organize a lot.

Answer (score 0):

well well well it turns out I may have had it correct several times. but here's the correct condition

```
 if ((minpon2[i]<minon2[i] && maxpon2[i]<minon2[i] || maxpon2[i]>maxon2[i] && minpon2[i]>maxon2[i]) || 
                    (min[i]>maxp[i] && min[i]>minp[i] || max[i]<minp[i] && max[i]<maxp[i])) { return 22; }
            }
```

The problem as it turns out was that when I had the conditions right and I was noticing the shifted down collision I was using an alternate set of vertices for my player which I had used for other purposes. which was exactly 100 pixels higher on the player than the collision box I thought I was using. I'm getting quite good I think as Its usually a simple problem that I just scanned over. I'll Definitely be simplifying my code and getting rid of all the trash I haven't been getting rid of that I was experimenting with.